# aes-128 cbc code generated from crypto and php is different

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

My node.js code is as shown below:

```
const testTempToken = (req, res) => {

    const temp_token = req.body.temp_token;
    const key_val = req.body.key_val;

    const temp_token_utf8_md5 = crypto.createHash('md5').update(utf8.encode(temp_token)).digest("bianry")

    const key = temp_token_utf8_md5;
    const iv = temp_token_utf8_md5;
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);

    const to_be_encrypted = utf8.encode(key_val);
    const encrypted = cipher.update(to_be_encrypted, 'utf8', 'base64');
    res.json({
        status: '200',
        data: encrypted
    });


};
```

My php code for this as shown below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CardTransaction extends Controller
{

    //this is the function that takes the parameter from API
    public function store(Request $request) {
        $tempToken = $request->token;
        $keyValuePair = $request->keyVal;
       // $encryptedString = $request->encryptedString;

         /* The code given below is for encryption */
        $protectPayAPI = new ProtectPayApi();
        $encryptedString = $protectPayAPI->setUtf8EncodeMd5HashTempToken($tempToken)
                ->encryptString(utf8_encode($keyValuePair))
                ->getEncryptedString();
                return response()
                ->json(['output' => base64_encode($encryptedString)]);

    }

}

class ProtectPayApi
{
    /* for temp tokens */
    private $_tempToken;

    /* md5 hash of utf8 encoded temp token */
    private $_md5HashUtf8TempToken;

    private $_encryptedString;
    private $_decryptedString;

    /**
     * @param string $tempToken
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setUtf8EncodeMd5HashTempToken($tempToken) {
        $this->_tempToken = $tempToken;
        $this->_md5HashUtf8TempToken = md5(utf8_encode($tempToken),TRUE);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Encrypts the string using the set $this->_md5HashUtf8TempToken
     * @param string $stringToEncrypt
     * @return $this
     */
    public function encryptString($stringToEncrypt) {
        $this->_encryptedString = openssl_encrypt(
            $stringToEncrypt,
            'AES-128-CBC',
            $this->_md5HashUtf8TempToken,
            OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
            $this->_md5HashUtf8TempToken
        );
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Decrypts the string using the set $this->_md5HashUtf8TempToken
     * @param string $stringToDecrypt
     * @return $this
     */

    public function decryptString($stringToDecrypt) {
        $this->_encryptedString = $stringToDecrypt;
        $this->_decryptedString = openssl_decrypt(
            $stringToDecrypt,
            'AES-128-CBC',
            $this->_md5HashUtf8TempToken,
            OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
            $this->_md5HashUtf8TempToken
        );
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getEncryptedString() {
        return $this->_encryptedString;
    }

     /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getDecryptedString() {
        return $this->_decryptedString;
    }
}
```

Input `temp_token(node)/token(php)` for both is

**0e359993-7ac0-4ce4-b00a-7a3644a38ca6a8e3706d-42cd-491e-90eb-97b6e2ac7b9b**

Input `key_val(node)/KeyVal(php)` for both is

**AuthToken=0e359993-7ac0-4ce4-b00a-7a3644a38ca6a8e3706d-42cd-491e-90eb-97b6e2ac7b9b&PayerID=1675506249460924&Amount=10.00&CurrencyCode=USD&ProcessMethod=Capture&PaymentMethodStorageOption=None&InvoiceNumber=Invoice123&Comment1=comment1&Comment2=comment2&echo=echotest&ReturnURL=http://kraftdigital.in/&ProfileId=2148409&PaymentProcessType=CreditCard&StandardEntryClassCode= &DisplayMessage=True &Protected=False**

`Now cipher string generated in node is`

**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**

`cipher string generated in PHP is`

**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**

is there anything missing in my node.js code. Becasue php cipher string is correct and verified.